# signed android app using private_key.pepk

Tags: android, signed-apk

I'm working on a project, I don't know the credential(key, password and path of keystore file) for signed apk for the app and unable to find it. I only have private_key.pepk file. How can I create signed apk so that I can upload it to play store.

Answer (score 0):

If you enrolled your App Signing by Google Play then you can contact support and send them a new pepk file.